# 'WindowsBase', 'PresentationCore', 'PresentationFramework' are missing from the target framework

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to load a solution in Visual Studio 2013 but I am receiving this message:

[image: Project Target Framework Not Installed]

When I click OK it shows another error message:

> Attempted re-targeting of the project has been canceled. Required
>   assemblies 'WindowsBase', 'PresentationCore', 'PresentationFramework'
>   are missing from the target framework.

I have all .NET Framework installed (I am running Windows 10) and I already tried the .NET Framework Repair Tool (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2698555).

Comment: Can you open that project file  in notepad and change .net version to 4.5 and try loading it in VS 2013

Comment: I changed `'<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>'` to 4.5 and VS can not load because it still appears the same error.

Comment: It works when I changed to v3.5! Thank You!

Comment: I had this error in VS2017, simply because the ".NET Desktop dev" component was not installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open that project file  in notepad and change .net version to < your project .net version > and try loading it in VS 2013

Answer (score 0):

When you get these message, you can do the following step by step:

1. open another project by +click on a yourprojectname.sln, so
   you have two visual studios open. (One with a working project).
2. RightClick on your projectname in the solution explore and
   choose "Unload project".
3. RightClick again on you project and choose then "Edit
   yourprojectname.csproj". Do this also with the project where you get
   the message in.
4. Compare these two files and change the items.
    and all under the

   Save the file and close it.

   RightClick again on you project and choose "Reload project"

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tK9Td.png)

Do you have ".Net Desktop Dev" ?
Checked Visual Studio Install.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you are downloading Unreal Engine 4.22 from source.

GitDepedencies.csproj

line

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

I have changed to the

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

The same for "HTML5LaunchHelper.csproj", "nDisplaylistener" and others.

I have been clicking "Do not load the project", and then clicked "Reload All".